# Is async/await no place in functional programming JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, promise, async-await, ecmascript-next

I am learning monad with JavaScript. Promise itself is monad, and is the right way to handle async side effects functionally. How about the es7 new player async/await, can we use it in functional programming of JavaScript? I feel like it falls well defined promise monad back to imperative way. Or there is a way to use async/await wisely enough to make function programming even easier?

Comment: I guess it's more about what most people ask for. They want to write async code as if sync. By saying so they actually mean imperative coding style. I agree, promises are fantastic and currently give them what they ask for functionally but people still can't fully harness them. They do things like nesting promises within each other instead of chaining. So for those at this moment they have the coroutines which solve this syncish coding problem and most probably coroutines will be replaced by async and await. Yes i don't think async and await introduce any forward leap concerning functional JS.

Comment: I feel async/await may encourage us to write more imperative code.

Comment: Note that Promises are *not* a monad as they auto-flatten `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(3))` is a promise of an int not a promise of a promise. There a good gateway to monads though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still can write asynchronous code in a functional style with it. `async`/`await` is nothing but sugar, just like `do` notation is in Haskell (though it is restricted to promises and not generic monads). If you are writing code with promises and feel that `async`/`await` would simplify it, then use it.

Notice that promises are often using side-effects (and asynchrony itself, by being in the time domain, might count as an effect), so an imperative style is often not the wrong approach. After all, even functional programs carry out side effects.